# validate a prestashop user registration field

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

Hi first thank you very much for reading me, I just started to learn how to create prestashop modules and I want to make a check of the birthday field of the registration (must be over 18 years old) user with prestashop 1.7.

I have tried to do it with hooks but I can't do it and I can't find any solution.

The important thing is that I need to do it from a module.
When I install and enable the module it should do the check.

Thank you very much : )

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by overriding Prestashop's Validate class. If you want to do this through a module follow below steps:

- Create a module([TUTORIAL](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/creation/))
- Create file "Validate.php" at `/modules/<module_name>/override/classes/Validate.php`
- Inside "Validate.php" file place below code:

```
<?php

class Validate extends ValidateCore
{

public static function isBirthDate($date, $format = 'Y-m-d')
    {
        if (empty($date) || $date == '0000-00-00') {
            return true;
        }

        $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
        if (!empty(DateTime::getLastErrors()['warning_count']) || false === $d) {
            return false;
        }
        
        $d->add(new DateInterval("P18Y"));
        return $d->setTime(0, 0, 0)->getTimestamp() <= time();
    }
}
```

It will be copied in `/override/classes/Validate.php` during the module installation, and removed automatically on uninstall.

```
$d->add(new DateInterval("P18Y"));
```

Line above will not let user create an account if provided date is below 18 years old.

After installing the module don't forget to delete `class_index.php` from cache folder so override is applied. (You can find it at `/var/cache/dev` or `/var/cache/prod`)